# Get non-zero values from string in R

Tags: r, string

I have two strings:

```
x1 = "03011000"
x2 = "13001000"
```

The strings have an exact overlap in their non-zero characters. I would like to get for every character position the max element.
So in this case the result would be:

```
result = "13011000"
```

The first character is a 1 because x2 has a 1 at the first position. The fourth character is also a 1 because x1 has a 1 at this position.
The way I go about it is the following:

```
paste0(mapply(pmax, strsplit(x1, ""), strsplit(x2, "")), collapse = "")
```

But this seems excessive as I have to split every character into its components and compare them. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using *raw* comparison:

```
rawToChar(as.raw(pmax(as.numeric(charToRaw(x1)), as.numeric(charToRaw(x2)))))
# [1] "13011000"
```

We could wrap it into a function:

```
foo <- function(x, y){
  mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
    rawToChar(as.raw(pmax(as.numeric(charToRaw(x)), as.numeric(charToRaw(y)))))
  }, x = x, y = y, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

x1 <- "03011000"
x2 <- "13001000"
foo(x1, x2)
# [1] "13011000"

x1 <- c("03011000", "ab", "123")
x2 <- c("13001000", "cd", "212")
foo(x1, x2)
# [1] "13011000" "cd"       "223"
```

Comment: Great option with serailaization/deserialize

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @akrun your solution was good too I think you should undelete it, you were just wrong that we should convert to numeric, as `max` / `pmax` work on characters too. And you can refactor it into a more compact form, just 50% slower than this solution on this example : `paste(do.call(pmax, strsplit(c(x1,x2),"")), collapse="")`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  It's okay,, I think it is only a very small change wrt to OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

> The strings have an exact overlap in their non-zero characters.

I assume this means that when both strings are nonzero, they are guaranteed to match?

If so, it is sufficient to find the positions with zeros in one vector and not in the other (with `setdiff`) and make the string edit:

```
r <- gregexpr("0", c(x1,x2))
w <- setdiff(r[[1]], r[[2]])
rr <- structure(w, match.length = rep(1L, length(w)), useBytes = TRUE)

x = x1
regmatches(x, rr) <- regmatches(x2, rr)
x
# [1] "13011000"
```